# How to predict multiple linear regression r

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to predict the next 24 months based on the following data from the electricity data set in the TSA package. I made a model using linear regression based on which the month and time.

```
library(TSA)
library(forecast)
data(electricity)
logdata = log(electricity)
month = season(electricity)
time = time(electricity)
model = lm(logdata~month +time(electricity))
summary(model)
```

However I am having difficulty trying to forecast 24 months into the future.

```
newelec= ts(rep(0,24), start=end(electricity), freq=frequency(electricity))
month = season(newelec)
mat = as.matrix(model.matrix(~month+time(newelec)+0)[,-1]) 
pred = forecast(model,mat)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, length(tmpdata) + 1, value = c(1973, : replacement has 396 rows, data has 24
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Tried to reproduce your code, got an error when defining `mat`, is the statement correct?

Comment: My apologies I forgot a line of code, I added it and think it should work now.